# PhP comparate hour to next hour

Tags: php

i have problem, on my code i try comparate database hour to current hour, for limit request per hour "forget password".

my code:

```
$hora_databse = date('h', strtotime($row["data"]) + 60*60);
$hora_now = date('h', strtotime(date("Y/m/d H:i:s")));
if($hora_databse > $hora_now) {
    $error = "send ";
} else {
    $error = "wait one hour";
}
```

Thanks for help. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What does this code do? You could just do this in SQL.. `strtotime(date("Y/m/d H:i:s")` is `time()`.. and `date` uses the current time by default so could just be `date('h');`.

Comment: i want code for execute command after one hour, in last operation i put on table date, and i want only can execute again after one hour

Comment: Why not just do something like `where timelastloggeding <= now() - interval 1 hour`? (might need the operation inverted there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with TIME.

Example:

```
<?php

$hour_database = 1534638067 + 60*60;
if($hour_database > time()) {
    $error = "Wait one hour to try again! :/ ";
} else {
    $error = "You can change your password now! :)";
}

echo $error;

?>
```

Note that *1534638067* is only a reference, so change to the variable that receives the data from your database. I don't know how you're saving time in your database, if it does not work try to save it using time().

Comment: (`unix` isn't a time, I think you want to say `epoch` there, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing)

Comment: Yeah! My English is a little rusty I didn't know how to say, anyway, thank you!

Comment: for get this time use strtotime($row["data"])) ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. How are you storing this data? With time(), date()?

Comment: i put date on mysql exemplo: date("Y/m/d H:i:s")

Comment: Try to save it using time();

Comment: this is complicated :ssss have one to convert?

Comment: Ok, just change $hour_database = 1534638067 to $hour_database = strtotime($row["data"])

Comment: i try this: $hour_database = strtotime($row["data"]) + 60*60; and all time say i can change

Comment: $hour_database = strtotime($row["data"]) + 60*60;
        if($hour_database > time()) {
         $error = "wait ";
        } else {
         $error = "go";
        }

Comment: and on database i have this: 2018/08/19 01:31:35

Comment: Check what $row["data"] is returning to you.